# Uploading data with ODBC conector in PowerBi

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, powerbi, odbc, amazon-athena

I have connect succesfully the ODBC with AWS account. I do not know how to add the data in my AWS catalogue, if I need Glue or other operator to connected and use the Amazon database to do my reports in Power Bi. I am in the last step of the video of mathew if you havent watch it, this is the steps I followed.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKdCr6vmq-o
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEmia.png)

I try to uplaod a excel file into AWS but I could not find it usefull since I need Amaon database to work in real time with my reports.